# Store random data in Postgres database from Python

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the data in this form:

> data={'[{"info": "No", "uid": null, "links": ["";, ""], "task_id": 1, "created": "2017-02-15T09:07:09.068145", "finish_time": "2017-02-15T09:07:14.620174", "calibration": null, "user_ip": null, "timeout": null, "project_id": 1, "id": 1}]', 'uuid': u'abc:def:ghi'}

I want to store this data in the Postgres DB. I have this query:

```
    quer1='UPDATE table_1 SET data = "%s" WHERE id = "%s" '%(data1,id)
    db_session.execute(quer1)
    db_session.commit()
```

This query does execute but doesn't store anything in the db. Datatype of data is 'text'. I am not able to make where I am wrong. Please help.

Edited::
I updated my query to this:

> quer1='UPDATE table_1 SET data = "%s" WHERE hitid = %s '%(data1,id)

Comment: What is the datatype of the `id` column? What is the value of `id` that you are using?

Comment: Your `data` variable is not a working Python code snippet. Overall it seems like this is not a complete, minimal example.

Comment: @MattMS datatype of id is varchar.

Comment: As @groteworld mentions, please update your question with an actual value you are using for `data`.

Comment: @MattMS Updated

Comment: @groteworld It was in the python code. I lately realized the query is wrong not the Python code. THanks for edit.
Kindly help me in saving data using this query.

Comment: Your updated `data` is still invalid Python code. It seems you are trying to create a dict but not giving the key before the JSON string.

Comment: @MattMS i have removed the python tag. This was not about python. It's just this query that is not working. I need to store the data given above in postgres db. 
This is the actual data i am getting which can't be modified.

Comment: Wrap your data in triple quotes (so `data1 = """whatever"""`) and then use the query in my answer.

Comment: @MattMS thanks for that suggestion. but it didn't work!

Comment: Then I'm afraid I can't help further. All I can say is make sure that the data you are inserting is a string, and make sure your execute call uses parameters. Also don't add extra quotes to the `%s` symbols in your query. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, **never** use `%` or `str.format` to insert values into your queries!!!

Assuming you are using psycopg2, your query should use the following format:

```
db_session.execute('UPDATE table_1 SET data = %s WHERE id = %s', (data1, id))
```

As @groteworld mentions, `data = {1,2,'3',[4],(5),{6}}` is not valid Python.
I will assume you are using a proper value for `data` in your actual code.